# Static ip adress for kubernetes pods with calico cni

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I'm currently using `10.222.0.0/16` network for my pods on a single node cluster test environment.

When I reboot the machine or redeploy pods they get the first ip address which has not been used previously. I want to prevent this from happening by assigning static ips for pods with calico.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Maybe multus, though it's not meant to replace your SDN. Better figure out how to configure your application not to suffer from IP changes -- let us know what's your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that approach would be against the dynamic nature of Kubernetes' IP layer. However, there is a solution found in the [Project Calico docs](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/use-specific-ip):

> Choose the IP address for a pod instead of allowing Calico to choose
> automatically.

Bear in mind that:

> You must be using the Calico IPAM.
>
> If you are not sure, ssh to one of your Kubernetes nodes and examine
> the CNI configuration.
>
> ```
> cat /etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist
> ```
>
> Look for the entry:
>
> ```
>  "ipam": {
>       "type": "calico-ipam"
>   },
> ```
>
> If it is present, you are using the Calico IPAM. If the IPAM is set to
> something else, or the 10-calico.conflist file does not exist, you
> cannot use these features in your cluster.